# Prestashop REST API URLs keep redirecting to index.php

Tags: nginx, prestashop

Every URL attempting to access the REST API of Prestashop is redirecting to index.php. May I know why and how can I solve this?

And I have activated the key with the appropriate permissions (please see attached screenshot). Yet, it's giving this error.

[image]

I am using Prestashop 1.7.6.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 x64, from a vultr.com cloud instance. It's running Nginx. I have checked out the answer in: [Prestashop Webservice api url redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475602/prestashop-webservice-api-url-redirection), but it's just saying that Nginx's config is doing this redirect. I've got enough knowledge about Nginx to change this config eg. I dunno which file, in which directory, and what to change.

Hopefully someone can help...

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess have:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

sow you can get access to api by yourdomain.com/webservice/dispatcher.php and for example to get address it will be webservice/dispatcher.php?url=addresses/1833